# IntegrityError on UserProfile and socialAuth in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-socialauth

I have a Django app with social-auth enabled. And I'm getting IntegrityError with my custom UserProfile.

Let's say I have three models in my Django app:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    vk = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class VKGroup(models.Model):
    gid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3000)

class UserGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(VKGroup)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('group', 'user',)
```

And when I try to create UserGroup with UserProfile and VKGroup, I'm getting Integrity Error:

> IntegrityError at /comments/addgroup (1452, 'Cannot add or update a
>   child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`Django`.`comments_usergroup`, CONSTRAINT
>   `comments_usergroup_user_id_75607d294cb3ec28_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')

Here's the code how I add new UserGroup:

```
@login_required
def add_group(request):
    user = request.user
    #profile exists here
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)
    vk_group = VKGroup(<some paramethers here to create valid group>)
    vk_group.save()

    user_group = UserGroup(user=profile, group=vk_group)
    user_group.save()

    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

I'm creating UserGroup with valid UserProfile and VKGroup and it worked fine until I integrated social-auth. Please help me to get the problem and fix it.

Thank you!

Here's my traceback:

```
File "./comments/views.py" in add_group
  145.             user_group.save() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  589.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  617.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
_save_table
  698.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in
_do_insert
  731.                                using=using, raw=raw) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in
_insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in
__exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  129.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /comments/addgroup Exception Value: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`Django`.`comments_usergroup`, CONSTRAINT `comments_usergroup_user_id_75607d294cb3ec28_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
```